# R rms package error when using rcs()

Tags: r, statistics, regression

Been looking into Harrell's `rms` package for R and I am getting an error whenever I try to use the spline function `rcs()` inside a formula.  This happens with all datasets.  Is there some R setting I am missing?

```
library(rms)

df = read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

m = lrm(admit~ rcs(gre), df)


Error in rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, fractied = fractied) : 
  unused argument (fractied = fractied)
```

What is "fractied"?  I haven't been able to find a clear explanation.

I'm using Windows 7, R version 3.1.0, rms version 4.2.0

Comment: Can't answer about fractied but the example above runs without error for me [rms V4.1-3 on R3.1.0, ubuntu 12.04]

Comment: Running rms_4.2-0  in the SnowLeopard release of R 3.1.0 Patched I also get no error. It appears that rcs is estimating a spline fit with 5 knots. There is no documentation about what happens when you only give a, x (predictor) argument and no argument to 'parms'. Looking at the code it does appear that there is a default of 5.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is some sort of system setting problem...